# Решено CSS выключатель (выбор из двух городов)

Tags: html, css, input, html-form

Мучаюсь уже долго: ... ожидаемый результат - поле с выбором из двух городов, так чтобы оба названия были видны, но было очевидно понятно какой из них выбран ( нетривиально, пусть это будет простое подчеркивание).

Выпадающий список использовать нельзя.

Уже есть: макет этого самого выключателя (источник вдохновления proto.io), проблема не видно второй город.

Понимаю что вся загвоздка где-то здесь:

```
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content:"Москва";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #999999;
}
    .onoffswitch-inner:after {
        content:"Минск";
        padding-right: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        color: #999999;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

Свои наработки выложил для удобства на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shilgen/xhevu3ve/1)

*Заранее, всем спасибо даже за комментарии)*

Comment: ну не видно явно из-за overflow: hidden; у контейнера вот сразу видно, что именно из-за этого  http://jsfiddle.net/xhevu3ve/2/

Comment: @binliz  ... убираю его,  там всё коряво становится(

Comment: Вы подобное имели ввиду? http://jsfiddle.net/xhevu3ve/4/

Comment: @VitaliyShevchenk o да именно то, преобразуйте свой комментарий в ответ, и я отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дополнительно значения для свойства content можно брать из data атрибутов в разметке.

```css
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 340px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 9px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  color: red;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #999999;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: attr(data-before);
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: attr(data-after);
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  margin: 15px;
  background: #A1A1A1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 166px;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner:after {
  color: red;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner:before {
  color: red;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner:after {
  color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"> 
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner" data-after="Минск" data-before="Москва"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: извиняюсь, а как? пусть data-city="moscow"  тогда как получить его значение  css?

Comment: Все просто content: attr(data-city);  http://jsfiddle.net/xhevu3ve/5/ Тут подробнее про функцию attr http://htmlbook.ru/css/attr